# where do I place themes.xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout

In what directory do I have to place my themes.xml in order that my android recognises the correct version?

I have two versions of themes.xml. One is used by tablets. And the other one shall be used for phones with large screens. I placed the one for tablets in the folder res\values-v11\themes.xml and the other one in res\values\themes.xml

Unfortunately someting doesn't work. I definied a textColor for textViews in each of the files with different colors, so that I can recognise the file which was chosen by the OS on different phones. It worked perfectly on a xoom tablet with android 3.2. On a galaxy s2 with 2.3.5 it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Here are the styles I use:
Tablet:

```
<style name='MyTheme' parent='android:Theme.Holo.Light'>



<style name='MyAutoComplete.red' parent='@style/MyAutoComplete'>
  <item name='textColor'>@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Non-Tablet:

```
<style name='MyTheme' parent='android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar'>

  <style name='MyAutoComplete.blue' parent='@style/MyAutoComplete'>
    <item name='textColor'>@color/blue</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your requirement is to track OS version by textView's color.

I have following suggestion. (Colors are for example only, you can change yourself)

1. res/values -> Yellow Color // Phone using 2.3.* or before
2. res/values-v11  -> Red Color // Phone using 3.0 or later
3. res/values-xlarge -> Green Color // Tablet using 2.3.* or before
4. res/values-xlarge-v11 -> Blue Color // Tablet using 3.0 or later

So a Xoom should show Blue, a S2 (2.3.*) should show Yellow, a Galaxy nexus should show Red.

Comment: ok, so my folder structure is  actually correct. I tried it with the colors and this worked for 2/3/4. It didn't work for number 1.

Comment: figured it out. Apparently the theme: android:`Theme.Light.NoTitleBar`overwrites the TextColors! I use now just android:Theme and the color is visible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a theme in `styles.xml` and place it in `res/values` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put "Tablet" in `res/values-xlarge` and "Non-Tablet" in `res/values`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two seperate xml files for the two themes to able to run the theme in the two seperate devices

Place both in resource :)

Hope it helps